# what does it mean to say natural deduction is paradoxical?

Tags: natural-deduction

In the very beginning of Chapter 2 Natural Deduction, page 8, in Jean-Yves Girard's book *Proofs and Types* (translated by Paul Taylor and Yves Lafont, published in 1989), the author writes:

> Natural deduction is a slightly paradoxical system: it is limited to the intuitionistic
> logic case (in the classical case it has no particularly good properties).

I don't understand what the author is trying to imply here. What are the so-called 'good properties' that happen in intuitionistic case while being absent or no good in classical case? Anyone can explain it?

Comment: Discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction#Classical_and_modal_logics).

Comment: Which merit should a paradoxical deduction have ?